# How can I hide acumatica Bills of material and Production Orders all screens using code

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How can I hide acumatica Bills of material and Production Orders all screens using code.
While publish my customization i ant to hide this two workspace and its Tiles and Screens.

Comment: I think the best way to hide screens is through Permissions rather than through code

Comment: For example, you can go the Access Rights by Screen

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i need to hide it through code because some screens from these workspaces i am showing in my customized workspace.  So  I have added these screens to my workspace and removed from  above mention workspace by sitemapmaint graph but unable to remove Tiles screen from site map. Through code i have removed above screens from site map so its working fine but in case of Tiles screen unable to hide

Comment: Not sure, as I never had that requirement. But I believe the supported way to hide tiles is through permissions only (which I understand does not meet your requirements) or updating the menu manually.  You could perhaps look into the MUITile DAC and database table - but I am not sure whether it's supported to modify these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly current issue is hiding the tile item.

Try opening the workspace, then click on the three dots menu and select Edit Menu.
[image]

Hover the mouse on the tile and click on the red X button to remove it.
[image]

After this change, add sitemap entry in customization (if it's not already there) or   use reload from database button. I haven't tested it but this used to work in previous Acumatica versions.

As it was mentioned in comments there is no official programmatic interface to manipulate the tile item.

Comment: Thank you ...I have checked  with this solution ...its working :)